# Highcharts - Column labels with different widths are not aligned

Tags: html, css, highcharts

I have a problem with long column labels. Then Highcharts make even column labels go in a wrong place. Here is a picture.

[image: Column labels are not aligned]

(Blow is very low)

I have searched in the Highcharts API but I can not find the right property to correct this. What do I need to change?

Comment: Highcharts wraps the labels according to the width. If you can provide the the code of what you have worked in a js fiddle that would help us to understand the problem better to give a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness. But Pawel Fus just gave the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `maxStaggerLines` to 1, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.maxStaggerLines).